# MySql query does not return rows when it ideally should

Tags: mysql

1. `select e1.cusip1 from edgelist e1 where e1.cusip1 = 37386;`
2. `select * from firm_metrics where prim_cusip = 37386;`
3. `select * from firm_metrics f where f.prim_cusip in (select e1.cusip1 from edgelist e1 where e1.cusip1 = 37386);`

I am trying to do a normal join or an inner query as shown in the third query however the third query does not return any rows. The first 2 queries are just the disintegrated queries of the 3rd query which do return rows. I have checked the excel from which I have loaded the data and it seems to work fine on other laptops, however does not work on mine. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are data types the same in these columns (cusip1 and prim_cusip)?

Comment: A simple join would do the trick right ? "select ... from edgelist e1 inner join firm_metrics f1 on f1.prim_cusip = e1.cusip1"

Comment: Yes the data types are the same as well, both are varchar.

Comment: A simple join isn't working as well. The thing is this query worked before. Then i did a minor adjustment in the excel and loaded it up again, tried the query didn't work. Then I rolled back my changes in the excel and tried, didn't work either and hasn't been working since then regardless of whatever changes i do to the excel. And those excels work on my friend's laptop and returns the result correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from firm_metrics f,edgelist e1 where e1.cusip1 = 37386;
```

Comment: This is returning the result since firm_metrics f isn't being used in the where clause.

Comment: firm_metrics and edgelist table have any relation?

Comment: Yup, the cusip1 and cusip2 from edgelist should be in prim__cusip in firm_metrics.

Comment: try this select * from edgelist e1,firm_metrics f where e1.cusip1=f.prim__cusip and e1.cusip1 = 37386;